# Bold code in listings environment

Tags: listings, bold, sourcecode

I want to do a box like this
[image]

but the bold text doesn't appear.

Edited:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,etoolbox,lmodern}
\definecolor{verbgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand*\prompt{}% empty default
\lstnewenvironment{sh}{%
  % redefine bash prompt:
  \def\prompt{user@linux:\textasciitilde\$\space}%
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verbgray},
    frame=single,
    framerule=1pt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    escapechar=@
  }%
}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{sh}
    @\prompt\space\textbf{date}@
    Thu Oct 25 13:51:54 EDT 2007
    \end{sh}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A couple pointers, you need a comma after `columns=fullflexible`.  Also, you're misreading the syntax of the escape character, it should be either `escapechar=@` or `escapechar=\@`.

Comment: Thanks I changed that, but still doesn't seems to work

Comment: Because of the indentation I'd add `gobble=4` to the setup. And I'd probably use `language=bash,keywordstyle=\bfseries,morekeywords=date` or something instead of escapechars. (This actually depends if `date` is the only occurence where you want bold...)

Comment: no there will be more ocurrences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified version of what you wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,etoolbox}
\definecolor{verbgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand*\prompt{}% empty default
\lstnewenvironment{sh}{%
  % redefine bash prompt:
  \def\prompt{user@linux:\textasciitilde\$\space}%
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verbgray},
    frame=single,
    framerule=1pt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    escapechar=@
  }%
}{}
% patch \lst@NewLine:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lst@NewLine
  {\hbox{}}% search
  {\hbox{}\prompt}% replace
  {}% success
  {}% failure
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{sh}
    @\textbf{date}@
    Thu Oct 25 13:51:54 EDT 2007
    \end{sh}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need fonts which will allow bold when creating `ttfamily`.  Hence the loading of

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: why I don't see mine in bold?

Comment: @Arturo you need a monospaced font with a bold variant